# Azure IoT hub device query pagination continuation token not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

When trying to create a paged website in .NET 6 of Devices connected to an Azure IoT hub I have found that it doesn't matter what the page number (pageNumber) I pass it always returns the first 10 devices. I think that the continuationToken is not formatted correctly or something along those lines but no error occurs.

```
registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("{iot hub connection string}")
int pageSize = 10;
var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", pageSize);
var pageToken = "skip=" + pageNumber * pageSize + "&total=" + pageSize;
var continuationToken = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageToken));
var page = query.GetNextAsTwinAsync(new QueryOptions() { ContinuationToken = continuationToken });
var deviceList = page.Result.ToList();
```

Comment: Did you put a break point at the line where the query variable is assigned and notice it's values? Do you see all the devices in the Azure IoT Hub populate into the query variable? Can you provide a reference of where you got a reference to this code resource from

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code you shared and noticed that the continuationToken does not seem to have an impact the returned result set. The continuationToken generated here using the code is a random string and I don't think it holds any information of pageToken. I have found a different approach to achieve the same result.

You can achieve pagination by leveraging the Skip and Take methods of IEnumerable in .Net. The query.GetNextAsTwinAsync().Result gives an IEnumerable of type Twin on which you can apply the Skip and Take methods to get paginated results.

Here is the code I have implemented to attain pagination of Azure IoT Hub devices

```
        registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connString);
        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = 1;
        var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices");
        var page = query.GetNextAsTwinAsync().Result.Skip(pageNumber*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        var deviceList = page.ToList();
```